# Array Matrix in java

Tags: java, arrays, dct

4x4 matrix array size will be split into several 2x2 matrix array. I want to know how matrix break automatically become a 2x2 array of 4x4 matrix?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tester;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Jhamsir Crown
 */
public class contoh {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double f[][] = new double[4][4]; //z merupakan hasil

    f[0][0] = 1;
    f[0][1] = 2;
    f[0][2] = 3;
    f[0][3] = 4;
    f[1][0] = 5;
    f[1][1] = 6;
    f[1][2] = 7;
    f[1][3] = 8;
    f[2][0] = 9;
    f[2][1] = 10;
    f[2][2] = 11;
    f[2][3] = 12;
    f[3][0] = 13;
    f[3][1] = 14;
    f[3][2] = 15;
    f[3][3] = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < f[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(f[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println("\n dipecah ke dalam beberapa Blok yang berukuran 2 X 2");
    System.out.println("\n Blok 1");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // for pada  ini untuk menampilkan data baris
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) // kolom
      {
        System.out.print("  " + f[i][j]); // Menampilkan data A [i][j]
      }

      System.out.println(); // memubuat baris ke bawah  
    }

    System.out.println("\n Blok 2");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // for pada  ini untuk menampilkan data baris
    {
      for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++) // kolom
      {
        System.out.print("  " + f[i][j]); // Menampilkan data A [i][j]
      }

      System.out.println(); // memubuat baris ke bawah  
    }

    System.out.println("\n Blok 3");

    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) // for pada  ini untuk menampilkan data baris
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) // kolom
      {
        System.out.print("  " + f[i][j]); // Menampilkan data A [i][j]
      }
      System.out.println(); // memubuat baris ke bawah  
    }

    System.out.println("\n Blok 4");

    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) // for pada  ini untuk menampilkan data baris
    {
      for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++) // kolom
      {
        System.out.print("  " + f[i][j]); // Menampilkan data A [i][j]
      }

      System.out.println(); // memubuat baris ke bawah  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we working with matrix it doesn't mean system use matrix type format to store the data. The data is store in continues memory location you can check this with help of pointer. So making a 2x2 matrix from 4x4 isn't difficult or any rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would wrap your matrices in classes to encapsulate the data. If you do it that way then your 'split' matrices could really just be pointers into other matrices.

Something like:

```
interface Matrix<V> {
    Dimensions getSize();
    V getValue(int row, int col);
}

class SimpleMatrix<V> implements Matrix<V> {
    ...
}

class SubMatrix<V> implements Matrix<V> {
    public SubMatrix(Matrix<V> parent, int row, int col, Dimensions size) {
        ...
    }

    public V getValue(int row, int col) {
        return parent.getValue(startRow + row, startCol + col);
    }
}
```

Then getting a list of all possible submatrices is fairly straightforward:

```
List<Matrix> allSubmatrices(Matrix matrix, Dimensions dimension) {
    List<Matrix> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.getSize().rowCount - dimension.rowCount; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix.getSize().colCount - dimension.colCount; c++) {
            list.add(new SubMatrix(matrix, r, c, dimension));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I split the matrix into small blocks for DCT method works by breaking into a 8x8 matrix NxN thoroughly,,, and transformation in each blocks are ... !!! but I do not know how to break into a 8x8 matrix NxN ... !!!